# contrite, detritus, diatribe

Tags: etymology

The words *contrite, detritus, diatribe* share the same root "trit" which means rub.

Why does contrite mean remorse, detritus mean debris, and diatribe mean criticism?

From etymonline, I found that con means "together", de means "away", and dia means "away".

Comment: ‘Dia-’ (from Greek _δια-_) means ‘through’. I can’t think of any combinations off the top of my head where it means ‘away’, but if there are any, it is a secondary meaning. Note also that the root in question, PIE _*terh₁-_ means not only ‘rub’, but also ‘grind, tear [by rubbing], turn, twist’. In Latin, the verb _terō_ means also both ‘rub, grind, wear away, thresh’—and it’s the root of the English verb ‘throw’, which has a further extension of the meaning (the German cognate, _drehen_, means ‘turn’).

Comment: Yes, exactly. For more detail, check out http://web.archive.org/web/20080625015505/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE527.html

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet perhaps _dia_ means _away_ in _diaspora_?

Comment: @terdon, no, that’s just ‘spread out across’ or ‘spread throughout [the earth]’. :-)

Answer (score 2):

*Contrite* comes from the French *contrit*, meaning bruised, hence penitent ; this word comes itself from Latin *conterere* = together-rub

*Detritus* comes from *deterere* = down-rub

Same root, then, but the meaning was considerably modified by the assimilation, in Catholic France, of penitence and suffering.

*Diatribe* is the offspring of quite a different root : French *diatribe*, from Latin *diatriba* (= a learned discussion), itself from Greek *diatriba* (= complete waste of time), where you find *tribein* (rub in the meaning "waste away")

Comment: _Τρίβω_ is not really from a different root, it is just an extension of the same root (Greek has lots of these strange-looking consonantal extensions to verbal roots in particular).

Answer (score 0):

*Contrite* comes from Old French *contrit* and directly from Latin *contritus*, literally "worn out, ground to pieces,", 
com- "together" + terere "to rub" (see throw (v.)).
However, in English, it's used in a figurative sense of "crushed in spirit by a sense of sin", and as such remorseful and apologetic.

*Detritus* comes from Latin *detritus* "a wearing away," from detri-, stem of *detere* "wear away" as in detriment. In geological sense, defined as an act of eroding away.

*Diatribe* is etymologically associated with "a wearing away (of time)," from *dia*- "away" + *tribein* "to wear, rub," from root *tere- (1) "to rub, turn, twist". Apparently from French, its sense of "invective" is more pertinent to the current definition.

Comment: citations please

Comment: Hello, Misti. If these are quotations, you **must** attribute correctly (or the answer may be deleted).